# cant install cabal package

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal, cabal-install

I have a problem with installing quickcheck from cabal on ubuntu 14.4 LTS. I have updated cabal, but when i try to install quickcheck an error comes up:

```
:~$ cabal install quickcheck
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring primitive-0.6.1.0...
Building primitive-0.6.1.0...
Preprocessing library primitive-0.6.1.0...
ghc: ghc no longer supports single-file style package databases (dist/package.conf.inplace) use 'ghc-pkg init' to create the database with the correct format.
Failed to install primitive-0.6.1.0
Configuring random-1.1...
Building random-1.1...
Preprocessing library random-1.1...
ghc: ghc no longer supports single-file style package databases (dist/package.conf.inplace) use 'ghc-pkg init' to create the database with the correct format.
Failed to install random-1.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
QuickCheck-2.8.1 depends on random-1.1 which failed to install.
primitive-0.6.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
random-1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
tf-random-0.5 depends on random-1.1 which failed to install.
```

I am pretty new ubuntu so I still dont know what to do in a situation like this. i really hope someone can help because it is for a school project which is do soon.

Comment: GHC and cabal version?

Comment: Are you using the haskell platform from the ubuntu repo? Please have a look at using a slightly more recent haskell platform/GHC.

Comment: Sorry like i said i am new to this so i dant know how to check for those?

Comment: I installed the haskell platform and there it says that cabal will be installed together with it. I have run cabal update after this too.

Comment: Did you read the error? `use 'ghc-pkg init' to create the database with the correct format`

Comment: if i try that as i believe it should be run:
:~$ ghc-pkg init
ghc-pkg: command-line syntax error
For usage information see 'ghc-pkg --help'.

Comment: `ghc --version`, `cabal --version`.

Comment: `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.2.20151105`,
`using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library`

Comment: GHC 7.10 with Cabal 1.16? That's a _very_ odd combination. As far as I know, Cabal 1.16 was for GHC 7.4.

Comment: A bunch of people ran into this when 7.10 came out, IIRC. I don't remember the right way to get everything installed. You need to update cabal-install, but the new version only works with new GHC.

Comment: Then you need to upgrade Cabal, or downgrade GHC.

Comment: My setup for Ubuntu is the following:

Install cabal and GHC version from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc.

(For instructions, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them).

Adjust PATH in $HOME/.bashrc to include /opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin and /opt/cabal/1.22/bin.

For extra-points: use sandboxes for everything. Run cabal update, and then modify your $HOME/.cabal/config, adding: require-sandbox: True. Every time I want to experiment, I create a new sandbox. Every project lives in its own sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours on installing/removing, the best way to install and configure latest cabal, ghc...

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have a very old cabal binary compared to your version of ghc.

You could jump through the package manager routes, or you could use the linux binary download from https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html

That should suffice to get you off the ground...